# applicationContext.xml error when importing web app into Eclipse

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a maven web application with applicationContext.xml that reports the error below:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
- cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'beans' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

The body of the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

  ${build.system.jobscheduler}
</beans>
```

The error goes away when I remove ${build.system.jobscheduler}.This is declared in the web/pom.xml as:

```
<build.system.jobscheduler><![CDATA[<!-- No job scheduler -->]]></build.system.jobscheduler>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When there is a job scheduler, what will be the string that will come in place of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the xml schema:

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

does not allow such expressions inside the `<beans>` element.

I don't know the content of **${build.system.jobscheduler}**.

If it is a class name you can try something like this:

```
<beans>
   <bean id="jobschedulerHolder" class="myapp.JobSchedulerHolder">
   <property name="jobschedulerClassName" value="${build.system.jobscheduler}" />
</beans>
```